# Get second occurrence of match from pythons positive lookbehind assertion

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the first and the second occurrence of a match in a string with python regex.

The string is : `QPushButton {background-color: #FF123456;color: #FF654321; border: none;outline: none;}QPushButton:pressed {background-color: #FF123456;}`

The Regex is: `(?<=color:)(([\w\ \#])*)`

On runing the code width:

```
 match = re.search(regEx, string)
 if match:
     match.groups()
```

I get as result only (' #FF0B9DF7', '7'). 
How can i get the second occurrence ( '#F654321') of the color?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [tinycss](http://pythonhosted.org/tinycss/).

Comment: Use `re.findall` method to get all the matching strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the correct function and accessing the result.

```
>>> re.findall(needle, haystack)
[(' #FF123456', '6'), (' #FF654321', '1'), (' #FF123456', '6')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `re.findall` is the method to use. But I'm not sure about your search pattern either... are you sure you want to get a list of tuples, with the first item containing a leading space and the second item being the last character in each match? If all you want is the color strings, I would do it like this:

```
regEx = r"(?<=color:)\s*(#[0-9A-Za-z]+)"
match = re.findall(regEx, string)
match
['#FF123456', '#FF654321', '#FF123456']
```

Now we just have a list of strings, that should be easier to work with than what you got before.

Comment: The regex shouldn't match only the color style, but thank for this solution. In addition I would change the letter range from A-Za-z to A-Fa-f for get a color style.